# Is it possible to conditionally import libraries in Java?

Tags: java, import, conditional-statements

Is it possible to check if a library exist before importing it in Java. For instance you have a code:

if (library.java exists)
  import library

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to do this?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because I have a function that generates some code (other functions) and later in my program I want to use those other functions so I have to check before using them if they exist

Comment: Looks like what you need is byte code manipulation. Please take a look at CGLib and JavaAssist. Libraries like hibernate use similar techniques to generate code at run time. Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible do do a conditional import.

Comment: It's not **literally** possible to make `import`, itself, conditional, but it's certainly possible to get essentially the same end result. This one-liner "no you can't do that" is, at best, *incredibly* incomplete.

Comment: That depends on how you define "the end result". You can't conditionally make the namespace available to the class file.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In retrospect, I may have fixated on "import" as literally being the "import" keyword. Rereading, that still looks like his intent to me, but I can also see your position. Clearly classes can be loaded in to the classloader conditionally. It might have been nice if the OP was more clear.